# Download a file hosted on node js web server on button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, webserver

I am new in nodejs.
I want to create a web server using nodejs which will host some static files. For that I have managed to done -

```
var http = require('http');

var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var serve = serveStatic("./");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var done = finalhandler(req, res);
  serve(req, res, done);
});

server.listen(8080);
```

I have a test file, say `hostedFile.zip` . 
When I hit url, `http://localhost:8080/hostedFile.zip`, this file gets downloaded.
Now I want to add button to webpage and download same file on button click.
What I have tried is-

```
var http = require('http');

var finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var serve = serveStatic("./");

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var done = finalhandler(req, res);
  res.end('<p><a href="/hostedFile.zip">Download</a></p>\n');
  serve(req, res, done);
});

server.listen(8080);
```

But its not working. Is there anything (concepts), that I am missing?

Comment: What specifically is not working? Do you get an error? Does something unexpected happen?

Comment: It just navigate to the page - ' http://localhost:8080/hostedFile.zip' , but does not download zip file.

Comment: @user7866584 did you get an answer to your question? I am facing the same issue. When I try to download via button.. it does not work/download.. but when I hit the url, it downloads the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `download` attribute in your link

```
res.end('<p><a download="file.zip" href="/hostedFile.zip">Download</a></p>\n');
```

> This attribute instructs browsers to download a URL instead of navigating to it, so the user will be prompted to save it as a local file. If the attribute has a value, it is used as the pre-filled file name in the Save prompt
>   [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

Comment: Tried this , but it is not downloading full file i.e. I have 800mb zip file , but its downloading onlt 150mb

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML `download` attribute. From [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp):

> Download file when clicking on the link (instead of navigating to the file):

```
<a href="/hostedFile.zip" download>
```

Comment: Not downloading full file i.e. I have 800mb zip file , but its downloading onlt 150mb